# Off-Screen Toggle Show Not Showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

We are working on integrating HighCharts into our existing ASP.NET sites and have come across a known bug. This bug is that elements that are initially set to display:none and then toggled to be shown display incorrectly because some browsers cannot calculate the dimensions of a hidden object (IE8 for example). The fix put forward [here](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=10712) and [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Why_does..)(at bottomof page) is to do this:

```
.hidden-container {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999em;
}
```

This is all well and good if you are using a jQuery CSS to set the locations. We are setting the locations and other attributes in the code behind like:

```
    If showExpanded Then
        collapsedPanel.Style.Item("Display") = "none"
        expandedPanel.Style.Item("Display") = "block"
    Else
        collapsedPanel.Style.Item("Display") = "block"
        expandedPanel.Style.Item("Display") = "none"
    End If
```

This I can edit for these chart panels to something like:

```
    If showExpanded Then
        collapsedPanel.Style.Item("Display") = "none"
        expandedPanel.Style.Item("Display") = "block"
    Else
        collapsedPanel.Style.Item("Display") = "block"
        expandedPanel.Style.Item("position") = "absolute"
        expandedPanel.Style.Item("top") = "-9999em"
    End If
```

We are toggling the hidden/show panels like so in a javascript file:

```
function showHidePanelToggle(ctlID, sPnlID, hPnlID) {
    var chkBoxID = $('#' + chkID);
    var controlID = $('#' + ctlID);
    var showPanelID = $('#' + sPnlID);
    var hidePanelID = $('#' + hPnlID);
    if (controlID.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
        chkID = false;
        if (controlID.is(':checked')) {
            showPanelID.slideUp('normal');
            hidePanelID.slideDown('normal');
        }
        else {
            showPanelID.slideDown('normal');
            hidePanelID.slideUp('normal');
        }
    }
    else {
        ctlID = false;
        if ((hidePanelID).is(':hidden')) {
            showPanelID.slideUp('normal');
            hidePanelID.slideDown('normal');
            chkBoxID.attr('checked', true);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            showPanelID.slideDown('normal');
            hidePanelID.slideUp('normal');
            chkBoxID.attr('checked', false);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have added checks to see if I am in the panels that are special (charts) and I am doing this:

```
if ((hidePanelID).position(':absolute')) {
                showPanelID.slideUp('normal');
                hidePanelID.slideDown('normal');
                chkBoxID.attr('checked', true);
                return false;
            }
            else {
                showPanelID.slideDown('normal');
                hidePanelID.slideUp('normal');
                chkBoxID.attr('checked', false);
                return false;
            }
```

This is not reshowing my panel (I am guessing because it is still set at -9999em.

My question is, how can I get my off-screen panel to show up correctly? We are not using a jQuery CSS file to set hidden/shown and rewriting the entire system to use this new CSS is a nonstarter, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the "position" and "top" values back to their defaults, within this block of code:

```
If showExpanded Then
    collapsedPanel.Style.Item("Display") = "none"
    expandedPanel.Style.Item("Display") = "block" // No need for this line?
    expandedPanel.Style.Item("position") = "static"
    expandedPanel.Style.Item("top") = "auto"
Else
    collapsedPanel.Style.Item("Display") = "block"
    expandedPanel.Style.Item("position") = "absolute"
    expandedPanel.Style.Item("top") = "-9999em"
End If
```